# FizzBuzz multi thread consumer producer

Tags: java, multithreading

I have the FizzBuzz question with couple of threads (producer and consumer)
I found this solution online : https://gist.github.com/masudak/5098917
But i am worried with a specific case,of a bad context switch ,  where 'isStop'
 is true but not all producers finished adding their numbers to queue.
Is it a real issue? or am i missing something?

```
public static AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);
public static ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Integer> queue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Integer>();
public static volatile boolean isStop = false; 

public static class Producer implements Runnable{

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while ( true ) {
            Integer counterValue = counter.incrementAndGet();
            if (counterValue <= 100) {
                queue.add(counterValue);
            } else {
                isStop = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }   
}

public static class Consumer implements Runnable{

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while ( true ) {
            Integer counterValue = queue.poll();
            if ( counterValue == null ){
                if(isStop){
                    break;
                }
                continue;
            }

            fizzBuzz(counterValue);
        }
    }


    private void fizzBuzz(Integer value){
        if( value % 15 == 0 ){
            System.out.println("FizzBuzz:" + value);
        } else if( value % 3 == 0 ){
            System.out.println("Fizz:" + value);
        } else if( value % 5 == 0 ){                
            System.out.println("Buzz:" + value );
        } else {
            System.out.println(value);
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: That's not C++.

Comment: Are you sure about the c++ tag?

Comment: FizzBuzz used to be such a nice, simple test of rudimentary programming knowledge so you could quickly and efficiently eliminate weak job applicants. Why in Crom's name did people have to add in threading?

Comment: @user4581301. To eliminate the weak applicants. Anyone that falls for this BS and tries to implement it using Threads is an immediate rejection.

Comment: @OP. Please fix your indentation. You know it's bad when you have thee curly braces stacked up in a vertical column.

Comment: yep, fixed it, its java i guess

Comment: ok, picture is included

Comment: Dima , you were much, much better off with the code, even with poor indentation, than you are with a picture. Rare is the compiler that can handle building from jpg, so now anyone who wants to try out the code has to type it into their IDE and may make transcription errors. Worse, they probably won't bother,and instead chose to downvote and move on to a more welcoming question.

Comment: there is a link to  a github project

Comment: Which is a link to an offsite resource. When that link rots away for whatever reason your question is of reduced use to future  people researching a similar problem.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Amen. Or in keeping with the Cimmerian, I shall dedicate my next slain foe to your honour.

Answer (score 0):

Despite bad formatting and other issues this is IMHO actually an interesting question. Yes, I believe that this code contains a theoretical issue although one that would be hard to expose. However if you modify the code just a bit by adding some explicit random `Thread.sleep` that would emulate accidental differences in performance of different threads for a real world tasks, you can easily see this issue. And then to reproduce the issue you need just 3 threads: 2 `Producer`s and one `Consumer`s. It is also critical that after adding `sleep` speed of `Producer`s became much slower than the speed of even single `Consumer` (unlike the original code where `Consumer`s were blocked by I/O operation while `Producer`s were not). I also reduced max value to 10 to shorten the logs. So here is the code:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;


public class fizzbuzz {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread th1 = new Thread(new Producer());
        Thread th2 = new Thread(new Producer());

        Thread th4 = new Thread(new Consumer());

        th1.start();
        th2.start();
        th4.start();
    }

    public static AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);
    public static ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Integer> queue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Integer>();
    public static volatile boolean isStop = false;

    public static class Producer implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                Integer counterValue = counter.incrementAndGet();
                final int MAX = 10;
                if (counterValue <= MAX) {
                    final int sleep = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(200);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(sleep);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    queue.add(counterValue);
                } else {
                    isStop = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static class Consumer implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                Integer counterValue = queue.poll();
                if (counterValue == null) {
                    if (isStop) {
                        break;
                    }

                    continue;
                }

                fizzBuzz(counterValue);
            }
        }


        private void fizzBuzz(Integer value) {
            if (value % 15 == 0) {
                System.out.println("FizzBuzz:" + value);
            } else if (value % 3 == 0) {
                System.out.println("Fizz:" + value);
            } else if (value % 5 == 0) {
                System.out.println("Buzz:" + value);
            } else {
                System.out.println(value);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

If you run this code a few times you might see something like this:

> 1
>   
>  2
>   
>  4
>   
>  Fizz:3
>   
>  Fizz:6
>   
>  Buzz:5
>   
>  7
>   
>  8
>   
>  Buzz:10

Note that **9** is missing. This happens because sleep for producer #9 was more than sleep for producer #10 so `isStop` was raised before actually all elements were added.

Or even something like this:

> 1
>   
>  2
>   
>  Fizz:3
>   
>  Buzz:5
>   
>  4
>   
>  Fizz:6
>   
>  7
>   
>  Fizz:9
>   
>  8

Note how **10** is missing. This is IMHO even more interesting: Producer #9 added value to the queue and on the next iteration while producer #10 was sleeping raised `isStop` flag because there is nothing more to produce.

One obvious workaround to this kind of issues is to use something like [CountDownLatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) to set `isStop` not when the first producer has finished its job but when the last one did.

Comment: thanks, was wondering, is there a more general solution possible for this issue, something that does not require language specific libraries?

Comment: @DimaS, although `CountDownLatch` is Java specific, it is not very complicated and you can emulate it. Moreover it is not a perfect solution for this goal as well. One simple different solution is just to have an `AtomicInteger` something like `activeProducersCounter` which is increased when a `Producer`'s thread is created and reduce just before `Producer` leaves its thread and change `isStop` condition to `activeProducersCounter == 0`. Under this condition `Consumer` will wait till the last `Producer` exits before exiting themself.